# Python Pandas Create Records from Complex Dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have processed some very complex nested json objects to get the following general dictionary format:

```
{'key1':'value1',
 'key2':'value2',
 'key3':'value3',
 'key4':'value4',
 'key5':[['value5', 'value6', 'value7'], ['value8', 'value9', 'value10']],
 'key6':[['value5', 'value6', 'value7'], ['value8', 'value9', 'value10']]}
```

In the list of lists, each list indicates something that should be an "individual transaction" equivalent.  Each transaction shares key1, key2, key3, key4 pairs.  There can be an arbitrary number of lists. I am trying to efficiently turn these into records in a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
 key1_field, key2_field, key3_field, key4_field, key5_or_key6_field_1, key5_or_key6_field_2, key5_or_key6_field_3, key5_or_key6_indicator 
     value1,     value2,     value3,    value 4,               value5,               value6,               value7,                   key5
     value1,     value2,     value3,    value 4,               value5,               value6,               value7,                   key6                
     value1,     value2,     value3,    value 4,               value8,               value9,              value10,                   key5 
     value1,     value2,     value3,    value 4,               value8,               value9,              value10,                   key6
```

Any assistance would be sincerely appreciated!  It has been a challenge enough getting this to this point.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As asked, I can post how I have been trying to approach this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'key1':'value1',
     'key2':'value2',
     'key3':'value3',
     'key4':'value4',
     'key5':[['value5', 'value6', 'value7'], ['value8', 'value9', 'value10']],
     'key6':[['value5', 'value6', 'value7'], ['value8', 'value9', 'value10']]}

df = pd.DataFrame({k : pd.Series(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()})
```

My remaining issue is that the single key values are NaN after the first row.

[image]

Comment: @Merlin Sure.  Understand that.  I have tried some options approaching this with dict.iteritems and list comprehensions but seem to have come to an impasse.  Any advice on how to dissect the problem is appreciated.

Comment: @Merlin I've updated this with the closest I have been able to get thus far.  Thanks, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.DataFrame({k : pd.Series(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}).ffill()
```

Comment: Thanks for the .ffill() addition!  I can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to read the dictionary as it is and reshape the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':'value1',
 'key2':'value2',
 'key3':'value3',
 'key4':'value4',
 'key5':[['value5', 'value6', 'value7'], ['value8', 'value9', 'value10']],
 'key6':[['value5', 'value6', 'value7'], ['value8', 'value9', 'value10']]})

df.set_index(['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']).stack().apply(pd.Series) \
  .rename(columns = lambda x: "value_" + str(x)).reset_index()

#     key1    key2    key3    key4  level_4 value_0 value_1 value_2
# 0 value1  value2  value3  value4  key5    value5  value6  value7
# 1 value1  value2  value3  value4  key6    value5  value6  value7
# 2 value1  value2  value3  value4  key5    value8  value9  value10
# 3 value1  value2  value3  value4  key6    value8  value9  value10
```

Comment: Wow, this is really succinct.  Unfortunately, I get a "ValueError: arrays must all be same length" if I just try to read the dictionary into a dataframe initially.

Comment: Did you try to read exactly the dataset you are showing in your question or you have a different dataset?

Comment: Yes, your option does indeed work on the mock dataset.  There can be an arbitrary # of lists in the lists of lists though.  I just used 2 for the example.

Comment: I updated this if you would be so kind as to take another look.  Thx

Comment: What's the difference between updated data and original data?